# Understanding the call method in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a hard time understanding how the call method is used in D3 and how that compares to its other uses in JavaScript.

My understanding of how the call method in standard JS is that it allows a function to be called within a particular context. For example:

```
let JoJo = {
    name: `JoJo`,
    age: 33
};

function sayName(){
  console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
}

sayName.call(JoJo);
```

This ensures that sayName() is called in the context of JoJo (i.e. as if it were a method of the JoJo object).

But that seems to be different than how it's used [here](https://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/) by Scott Murray:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .orient("bottom");
svg.append("g")
    .call(xAxis);
```

As Murray explains:

> D3’s call() function takes a selection as input and hands that
>   selection off to any function...That g becomes the selection for the
>   next link in the chain. call() hands that selection off to the xAxis
>   function, so our axis is generated within the new g.

So in the first example, call is being used to evoke a function within the context of a particular object (which call takes as its argument). In the second, it's just passing an object along to a function (which call takes as its argument).

I'm fairly new to both JS and D3, but it seems to me like there are two pretty different things going on in these examples. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which has nothing to do with D3 [`selection.call`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call): different methods, same name.

As a curiosity, internally D3 `selection.call` uses [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which is quite similar to `Function.prototype.call`. By the way, D3 has other methods which have the same name of vanilla JavaScript methods, like `selection.filter`, that one can confuse with `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: They're completely different! Well, that is both a little embarrassing to hear, but also a little satisfying. I kept looking at the two applications (one in JS, the other in D3) and thinking I was stupid for not being able to see how they were the same... Thanks very much!